# bash script to get all strings used in an UI element in Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash

Anyone know how I would create a bash script to scan my xcode project for all strings.

Or if not a bash script, then some way to scan all strings in my xcode project,

thanks

Edit:

So if in code there is:

label.text = "Hello"

The script would get the string hello

Comment: Is this for localization? Xcode already has tools to help with that.

Comment: @rmaddy Nope, not for localisation, I want to be able to collect all fo the strings, then do some sort of processing on them

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See `man strings`.

Comment: What are you really asking? Are you asking someone to write the script for you? Creating a bash script requires you open a text editor and write the script. I'm not trying to be a jerk, just trying to understand what you are really asking. One other thing, you need to have criteria for "string". Because there are alot of strings that can exist which are not anything you want to surface. For example, the name of an asset. Your strategy is to know where to search and what criteria you have for what a "string" is.

Comment: @MobileBen Oh that explains what you guys want. 

So I am trying to search for all strings which are being used in a UI element.

I am not asking for anyone to create it, if they could and it was easy then that would be appreciated, if not then the instructions to do it would be nice too. Thanks Ben for clarification

Comment: @KyleGraham is what strings you want arbitrary? Ex. Only on UILabels or on specific instances? Approaches greatly depends on that.

Comment: @MobileBen Just on UI objects, so UIView and subclasses, UITableView Headers, rows and any ui objects in cells for example.

So anything that is displayed to the user